# IFrame on Heroku

Tags: iframe, heroku

I have an IFrame, on a page hosted on Heroku like this:

<iframe data-src="http://jade-lang.com/" class="scaled_iframe" style="height: 700px;"> </iframe>

Running my project locally, or using Foreman works. I even have the same project hosted on Azure and it works fine, but the IFrame is blank when it is hosted on Heroku.
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve the same problem. As I understand it, Heroku only allows you to make calls to https. I haven't figured out how to get around this yet. Hopefully we can find a solution!

Comment: I found a solution to my problem (specific for TimelineJS) in which I pointed directly to AWS instead of the CDN. I'm not sure whether this will help you or not. Good luck!